# Single line (DOTALL) regex matching more than I want

Tags: java, regex

I'm having some issues with single-line regex (or DOTALL for Java guys).
I want to match each one of these set directives on a document.
My regex is this one:

```
\{\%\s*set\s+(\S+)\s*\%\}.+\{\%\s*endset\s*\%\}
```

And my target content to match looks something like this:

```
{% set var1 %}
  some multiline 
  really long content
{% endset %}

<other random code>

{% set var2 %}
  some multiline 
  other really long content
{% endset %}
```

The problem with this regex is that the first match (and only in the whole document) begins at {% set var1 %} and ends at {% endset %} from the second code block.
I tried using lookahead and lookbehind with no results.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using Java, try using `.+?` instead of `.+`.  The first matches as few characters as possible to make things match; the second gobbles up as many as it can.

Comment: Yeah as everyone has said it's all about [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the javadoc officially calls this a "reluctant" quantifier instead of "lazy".  Personally, I prefer "stingy".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to follow `.+` with `?` for a *[non-greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)* match.

```
\{%\s*set\s+(\S+)\s*%\}.+?\{%\s*endset\s*%\}
                         ^
```

**Note**: You do not need to escape `%` because it is not considered a character of special meaning.

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wK4mJ9)

Comment: +1, esp for the markup artwork (lovely caret `^` below the `?`) :)

Comment: Additional informations about subject: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked smoothly perfect. Didn't know that about non-greedy matches.